# Batch processing with Java EE/EJB3

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-file

I have a requirement like below.

Already there is a Websphere server and an MDB module present that persists messages in a database table. Each row will be marked with an INSERTED status in a column.

Now we need to develop another app or batch processing application to pick those messages up and process each row in that database and mark those status to Completed once processing completed.

What is the best way to do that? We heard EJB 3.1 Singleton Startup beans will be useful for starting the batch app?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a second JMS queue for processing the messages. As part of the transaction of writing the message to the database add the ID of the message to the new queue.

Your processing application could then be done as an MDB attached to this new queue. This separates the receiving of messages from the processing of them so you can manage your MDB pool sizes accordingly. Also means no need to poll the database to check for new messages.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I think if we process one by one the above will be a solution. But the message i m going to process needs a synchronization between them. For example there are 100 rows in DB and 3 of the messages having same id . If we have three MDB picks those 3 messages how to synchronize those? is there any solution since we need a batch processing with synchronization between them.Thanks in advance

Comment: Then I think you'll need to define how the processing should be triggered. If the messages are in groups do you need to wait until you've received the whole group before processing them? How do you know when the whole group is received?